# Possibilities to repeat password-based derivated key?

Tags: function, passwords, key, repeat, kdf

A few months ago I entered to cryptography, and I have a doubt.
Technically, a PBKDF, converts any password (with any keylength), to a one key with a specific keylength. I understand this is for can use any user entered password with cipher algorithms, resulting no errors of keylength.

For example, if AES 128 accepts 128 bit key size, I have 2^128 possibilities to found the correct key (X) when I decrypt with brute force. But user password possibilities are infinites (in theory, in practice a far away keylength value delimits possibilities). So, a infinite number of user passwords when program applies a PBKDF, becomes to the same 128 bit derivated key (X). Anyway, minimum a 128 bit user password, applying PBKDF, results the correct derivated key (X). This is true? I'm only intented apply logic to concept.

Anyway, I remember 128 bit keylength brute force implies very much time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course, there are many more possible passphrases than there are
keys. On the other hand, assuming the hash function is good, finding a
collision would take 2^64 work, and finding a preimage would take 2^128
work. So this is not a problem in practice.

---

Edit in reply to comment:

It sounds like you're saying that you can pick a nice long random
password, but it's possible it will generate the same hash as a very
short one? Well, yes, it's possible, but with probability so low that in
practice it's not worth worrying about.

Let's consider all the possible 8-character passwords. 94 printable
characters, raised to the 8th power, gives fewer than 2^53
possibilities. Out of a universe of 2^128 hashes, the probability of
hitting one of these by accident is less than 2^-75, or less than 1 in
10^22. It's far more likely we'll be hit by a major asteroid strike and
civilization will end.

Comment: I understand it, and the concept of collision, but is it possible a case of a 16 bit entered password by bruteforce (because in that occasion it started with "aa"), becomes the same derivated-key of a 192 bit password entered by user ("c7Pe%_3rA2=xgKl-02a3e93w")? 

Although I putting a 16 bit password (2 characters), the pbkdf returns a 128 bit derived password (if that case). They can always try it...

Comment: hahaha, surely, but I think if in that moment I were eating an ice cream, the hash would change and the asteroid would collision with the poor moon.